# Fixtures for Mongoengine with Django not working

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am using Mongoengine(version: 0.9.0 ) with Django(version: 1.8).
This is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
  }  
MONGO_DBNAME = "mydatabasename"
MONGO_HOSTNAME = "localhost"

connect(MONGO_DBNAME, host=MONGO_HOSTNAME)
```

I want to have fixtures for the application. I have created initial_data.json in myapp/fixtures/ location.

When I run the command `python manage.py dumpdata` , I get the following error :

> CommandError: Unable to serialize database: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Questions:

1) Any workaround for this problem ?

2) Is there any other way to load the initial data ?

**[References](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) at this link**

Thank you

Comment: I'm in the exact situation, have you found a way to load initial data with mongoengine?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoengine itsn a backend(in django terminology). Its has own models (schemas) and DOM (like ORM in docuemnt db's) but it dont have a Django backend adapters.

You can use it. But there is issue while workind with out-of-box Django solution like Tests, Fixtures, etc.
You need to write your own loader, sadenly but true.

I see 2 options here:

- You can try to use [Django MongoDB Engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
- You can write your own loader for mongodb

Ill write my own fixture loader for tests.
I have a json file where mapped all fixture file ill need to load to db.
So a fast example here:

```
import bson
import os
from django.conf import settings
from mongoengine.connection import get_db

def _get_db(self):
    self.db = get_db()

def _load_fixtures(self, clear_before_load=True):
    """
    Load to db a fixtures from folder fixtures/{{DB_NAME}}/{{COLLECTION_NAME}} before each test.
    In file fixtures.json mapped collection name and file name for it.
    """
    fixture_path = lambda file_name: os.path.join(settings.FIXTURES_DIR, self.db.name, file_name)
    with open(settings.COLLECTION_FIXTURES_PATH) as file_object:
        db_collections = loads(file_object.read())
        for collection_name, filename in db_collections.items():
            collection = self.db[collection_name]
            if clear_before_load:
                collection.remove()
            path = fixture_path(filename)
            if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isfile(path):
                with open(path, 'r') as raw_data:
                    collection_data = bson.decode_all(raw_data.read())
                    for document in collection_data:
                        collection.save(document)
```

Comment: Care to add an example of the json format you used?

Comment: @codervince i get a fixture_map.json (this is a settings.COLLECTION_FIXTURES_PATH) and in this file a get a valid json data like {"right": "right.bson", "user": "user.bson" ....} and so on. Key: value in this file is collection_name and file_name (not path to this file!) in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for fixtures on `mongoengine`, and I don't think the `mongoengine` team is continuing the plugin as of version 0.9.0.

What I ended up doing to load initial data for mongoDB is to create a script called `startup.py` in my project folder.

startup.py:

```
from {{app}}.models import Sample

def init():
    if Sample.objects(name="test").count() == 0: # a flag to prevent initial data repetition
        Sample(name="test").save()
```

Next is to run this script on Django's startup. The entry point of Django project is when `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is first loaded at `wsgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{project_name}}.settings")

import {{project_name}}.startup as startup
startup.init()

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

With this setup, when you run `python manage.py runserver`, the `init()` on `startup.py` will run and the data you set will be inserted to the DB.

Hope this helps.